# JSF components align

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper

i have crated a jsf page "login.jspx", when i preview it in the jdeveloper browser the align of components is to the left as i designed it, but the problem occurs when i deploy the project and run it, the page allign appears to the right !!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1256'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
          xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" xmlns:dvtt="http://xmlns.oracle.com/dss/trinidad/faces">
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="true" doctype-root-element="HTML"
                doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"
                doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1256"/>
    <f:view>
        <trh:html binding="#{backing_login2.html1}" id="html1">
            <trh:head binding="#{backing_login2.head1}" id="head1">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256"/>
            </trh:head>
            <trh:body binding="#{backing_login2.body1}" id="body1">
                <h:form binding="#{backing_login2.form1}" id="form1">
                    <p>
                        Welcome to the login Page, Please enter your email and password in order to continue
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <tr:panelFormLayout binding="#{backing_login2.panelFormLayout1}" id="panelFormLayout1">
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <h:panelGroup binding="#{backing_login2.panelGroup1}" id="panelGroup1">
                                    email
                                    <h:inputText binding="#{backing_login2.inputText1}" id="inputText1"/>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </f:facet>
                        </tr:panelFormLayout>
                    </p>
                    <tr:panelFormLayout binding="#{backing_login2.panelFormLayout2}" id="panelFormLayout2">
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <h:panelGroup binding="#{backing_login2.panelGroup2}" id="panelGroup2">
                                <f:verbatim>
                                    password
                                </f:verbatim>
                                <h:inputText binding="#{backing_login2.inputText2}" id="inputText2"/>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                    </tr:panelFormLayout>
                    <h:commandButton value="Login" binding="#{backing_login2.commandButton1}"
                                     id="commandButton1" action="#{backing_login2.commandButton1_action}"/>
                </h:form>
            </trh:body>
        </trh:html>
    </f:view>
    <!--oracle-jdev-comment:deviceCategory:pda-->
    <!--oracle-jdev-comment:auto-binding-backing-bean-name:backing_login2-->
</jsp:root>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the locale of your system and of your browser? Could it be a right-to-left based locale?